# SCSS to Style.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, npm, sass

Long story story, the main developer that worked on this is no longer with the company and I have to take over the project that they built out - So all help would be appreciated with this.

I'm not too familiar with WordPress nor SCSS/Foundation so this will be a learning process. I need to make a css change and deploy it, but it's not showing the changes on my local environment at all.

Here is the knowledge that I have:
- Foundation was used to build this
- SCSS is being converted to Style.css
- https://cdn.site.pl/wp-content/themes/sites/style.css?ver=4.9.10 - There is a version being applied to the end of style.css

Here are the tasks that are in my gulpfile.js:
[image]

Here is his documentation:

> The default gulp task runs both gulp scripts and gulp styles. To run
>   this task, navigate in Terminal to the project's htdocs directory, and
>   type:
>
> gulp

I get this in response:

> [14:00:37] Task never defined: default
>   [14:00:37] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks

Below, I will be providing the whole gulpfile.js file

```js
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const {
    src,
    dest,
    parallel,
    series,
    watch
} = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Usage in gulp: gulp task-name --theme=theme-name
// Default value is 'f-sites'
const themeName = argv.theme ? argv.theme : 'f-sites';

// GULP CONFIG
const config = {
    themeName: themeName,
    themeDirectory: `wp-content/themes/${themeName}`
};

// GULP TASKS

// SCSS/CSS TASKS
//==================================================

function sassToCss() {
    const nodeModulesSassPaths = [
        'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
        'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick',
        'node_modules/jquery-fancybox/source/scss',
        'node_modules/font-awesome/scss'
    ];

    const srcPaths = [
        `${config.themeDirectory}/scss/theme.scss`,
        `${config.themeDirectory}/scss/theme-rtl.scss`
    ];

    return src(srcPaths, { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(sass({ includePaths: nodeModulesSassPaths }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 10'] }))
        .pipe(dest(`${config.themeDirectory}/css`, { sourcemaps: true }));
}

function cssConcatLTR() {
    const srcFiles = [
        `${config.themeDirectory}/css/wordpress.css`,
        './node_modules/animate.css/animate.css',
        `${config.themeDirectory}/css/theme.css`,
    ];

    return src(srcFiles, { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(concat('project.css'))
        .pipe(dest(`${config.themeDirectory}/css`, { sourcemaps: true }));
}

function cssConcatRTL() {
    const srcFiles = [
        config.themeDirectory + '/css/wordpress.css',
        './node_modules/animate.css/animate.css',
        config.themeDirectory + '/css/theme-rtl.css'
    ];

    return src(srcFiles, { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(concat('project-rtl.css'))
        .pipe(dest(`${config.themeDirectory}/css`, { sourcemaps: true }));
}

function cssMinifyLTR() {
    const plugins = [cssnano()];
    return src(`${config.themeDirectory}/css/project.css`)
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(rename('style.css'))
        .pipe(dest(config.themeDirectory));
}

function cssMinifyRTL() {
    const plugins = [cssnano()];
    return src(`${config.themeDirectory}/css/project-rtl.css`)
        .pipe(postcss(plugins))
        .pipe(rename('style-rtl.css'))
        .pipe(dest(config.themeDirectory));
}

exports.default = parallel(
    series(
        sassToCss,
        parallel(cssConcatLTR, cssConcatRTL),
        parallel(cssMinifyLTR, cssMinifyRTL)
    ),
    series(jsConcat, jsMinify)
);

exports.styles = series(
    sassToCss,
    parallel(cssConcatLTR, cssConcatRTL),
    parallel(cssMinifyLTR, cssMinifyRTL)
);

exports.scripts = series(jsConcat, jsMinify);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the version of gulp-cli, you can try to upgrade it.

Relevant issues:
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli/issues/191
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1634

Comment: You are totally on the right track, my local version was on 4.0.0 and after updating to 4.0.2, it finally makes the gulp command work, but it's not pushing any updates to my local environment so at least one step is complete.

Comment: Does your site named "f-sites"? Check the comment:
`// Usage in gulp: gulp task-name --theme=theme-name`
You can try `gulp styles --theme=your-theme-name"` to see if it would help.